# IIF binding multiple conditions in ASP.NET gridview item template

Tags: asp.net

This works:

```
Text='<%# IIf(Eval("Likes") = "0", "N/A", "some text")%>'
```

This doesn't:

```
Text='<%# IIf(Eval("Likes") = "0", "N/A", IIf(Eval("Likes") = "1", " some text", "Other text")%>'
```

I am trying to add another conditional statement to this asp textbox binding. Does it only work for one condition? Or can I use an "Or IIF" or something like that?

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks like the second version is missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can chain IF condition all you want. For example:

```
<%# IIf(Eval("Likes") = "0" And Eval("Likes2") = "0", "N/A", "some text")%>
```

The first part of the IIf statement is your condition and you can chain it all you want.

Yes I did missunderstood you but the answer is still yes you can do it. Consider the following code:

```
    Dim Test1 As Boolean = True
    Dim test2 As Boolean = False
    Dim Test3 As String = IIf(test2, "True", IIf(Test1, "True", "False"))
```

This would be more like:

```
If Test2 Then
   ' Some code
Else
   If Test1 Then
      ' Some code
   End If
End If
```

Is that what you wanted or did you mean:

```
If Test2 Then
    ' Some code
ElseIf Test1 Then
    ' Some code
EndIf
```

As far as I know the 2nd option cannot be done with IIf statement.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I want to do an "ElseIF", not an and/or. For example, <%# IIF(Eval("Likes") = "0", "text is this" Elseif IIF(Eval("Likes") = "1", "text is that", Else, "text is something else"